# SQL Dates difference in number of days

Tags: mysql, sql

I try to get results in number of days between the **issue.date** and **today's date**. My SQL gives me format **dd.mm.YYYY as int[11]** and I convert it to **varchar [11]**  as the first format gives time since zero when exported to csv or xls.

So, my question is how to change int / varchar to date format to calculate difference between that date and today. Today's date is in datetime format.

Below is used to convert

```
CONVERT (VARCHAR(11),DATEADD(day,issue_date,'1971/12/31'),106) AS IssueDate
```

Format is **dd mm YYYY**.

I use `CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), GETDATE(), 106)` 
to get the same format but I do not know how to change to date format.

Note: I can not create any variables in the environment I work.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help. And your question is tagged "mysql", but your syntax is SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

Your question just doesn't fully make sense.  You should be storing date/times using *native* formats, not strings.  Not numbers.  Period.  That is the right way to store the date/time values.  Then you use date/time functions (such as `datediff()`) on the proper types.

When you do, you can just use `datediff(day, issue_date, getdate())`.

If for some reason you have dates in the format DD.MM.YYYY, you can use `convert(date, ddmmyy, 104)`.  Supported types are in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#date-and-time-styles).

Answer (score 1):

The `DATEDIFF()` function is use to find Difference between two dates. The `DATEDIFF()` has three parameters  as list below:

1 :- DATAPART (DAY,HOURS,MONTH,YEARS,SECONDS etc)

2 :- START DATE

3 :- END DATE

Example:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY , '2017-12-10',GETDATE()) // Result should be 151
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is rather easy:

```
CONVERT (date,DATEADD(day,wo_header.issue_date,'1971/12/31'),106)
```

and

```
CONVERT(date, GETDATE(), 106)
```

and then `(DATEDIFF (day,CONVERT(date, GETDATE(), 106), CONVERT (date,DATEADD(day,issue_date,'1971/12/31'),106) )) AS 'Days open'`